# Assign one task to one customer per day in task assignment Optaplanner

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I want help regarding Optaplanner task assignment changes, below is the complete information about the same:-

I have 70 tasks each task takes 2 to 8 hours which is defined for each task, the priority of each task is low and there is a low affinity between employees and customers, these tasks are associated with 37 customers.

My question is that how can I assign these tasks to employees such that if a task of a customer is assigned to an employee then for that day another task of that customer shall not be assigned to the same or another employee. Can someone help with drl rule or java constraint for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your data model, I'm going to make some assumptions on the fields available. The constraint could look like this:

```
.from(Task.class)
.ifExistsOther(Task.class, 
    Joiners.equal(Task::getCustomer), 
    Joiners.equal(Task::getDay))
.penalize("Two tasks for the same customer on the same day", ...)
```

It's up to you to decide how hard the penalty should be. If you want to eliminate this situation, you should make it a hard constraint - a solution with this constraint broken will not be feasible.

(EDIT) There is also another option, and that is to make the situation impossible in the data model. If you create one planning entity for each customer+day combination, it will be absolutely impossible for a single customer to have more tasks happening on one day.